# Shell script to list out all the directories in folder and run command for each of them

Tags: bash, shell

I have to write a script to find all the folders in a specific directory and run a command for each one of them.

For example: there are 5 folders listed as

- splunkforwarder_TEST_MLC_app04/
- splunkforwarder_TEST_MLC_app06/
- splunkforwarder_TEST_MLC_app08/
- splunkforwarder_TEST_MLC_app10/
- splunkforwarder_TEST_MLC_app02/

it should run following command

- splunkforwarder_TEST_MLC_app02/bin/splunk start
- splunkforwarder_TEST_MLC_app04/bin/splunk start
- splunkforwarder_TEST_MLC_app06/bin/splunk start
- splunkforwarder_TEST_MLC_app08/bin/splunk start
- splunkforwarder_TEST_MLC_app10/bin/splunk start

Comment: Do you want to run `splunkforwarder_TEST_MLC_app02/bin/splunk start` in directory `splunkforwarder_TEST_MLC_app04/` or in directory `splunkforwarder_TEST_MLC_app02/`?

Comment: the command can be run from parent directory. no need to cd each individual directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
for dir in splunkforwarder_TEST_MLC_app*/; do
  [[ -x "$dir"bin/splunk ]] || continue # skip if there is no splunk here
  "$dir"bin/splunk start
done
```

- the trailing `/` in the glob expression expands to just the directories `splunkforwarder_TEST_MLC_app04/`, `splunkforwarder_TEST_MLC_app05/` etc.

Answer (score 0):

well this is rather easy with some shell expansions... you wouldn't even need to use regular expressions or find and xargs for that matter... 
I would do it with * wildcard but the problem here is how would you like to handle the output of the commands...

For just the answer to the specific question at hand use:

```
splunkforwarder_TEST_MLC_*/bin/splunk start &
```

The "&" is just to send the process to the background and allow the shell to execute the remaining commands.

Comment: Let me know if you need to handle the output for each command or if you for example need to target specific directories (i.e. a subset of many similar directories) and there are unwanted targets on these command.

Comment: unfortunately its not working.                                                     dell425srv autoengine /dell425srv1/apps/SplunkForwarders/
bash$ ./splunkforwarder_TEST_MLC_app* /bin/splunk start &
[1] 25599
-bash: ./splunkforwarder_TEST_MLC_app02: is a directory
[1]+  Exit 126                ./splunkforwarder_TEST_MLC_app* /bin/splunk start
dell425srv autoengine /dell425srv1/apps/SplunkForwarders/

Comment: and it will be better if we can handle the output as well. after running the command the output will show some text and if the command is successful it display [ OK ] otherwise it contain [ FAILED ]

Comment: Are you by any chance leaving a space between the asterisk and the slash in the command? ok what you need might be better done with a loop according to what you are saying.

Comment: sorry my bad. removed the space and getting different error. "Parameters must be in the form '-parameter value'
"

Comment: This will not do the right thing.  It will make a single invocation of bin/splunk and pass all other bin/splunk directories as arguments.

Comment: Sorry I got distracted when I was going to suggest a for loop... kinda different than what codefoster posted but codefoster made it better than what I was thinking...